# Is it possible to control a child component in react if the parent component render many times?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-props, react-state

I am working on the issue regarding parent component render twice and child component also render twice. the existing code for the parent is

```
<childform
  value ="name"
  serverapi={this.valueservice.api}
  update={this.update}
/>
```

the child component start render using

```
componentDidMount()
{
   this.callservice(serverapi)
}
```

since its componentDidMount function called twice, the API also render twice which has to be avoided, each time the parent render the child's state is been refreshed so I cannot compare with the state, is it possible anyway to check or solution to this issue that I can refer? that resolves how many time I call the parent it call the API once

Comment: If the component is not mounting again componentDidMount will only run once. Please check your upper components which are causing the call to API multiple times

Comment: yes agree, I have existing scenario code which developed by another developer which render unwantedly. since parent called child twice, the child api also called twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the update prop you are passing to `childform` is a boolean indicating whether or not the component should rerender. If that is the case you can use the `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle method the to check if there is an update and only rerender when true:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //You can perform more logic here such as 
  //return this.props.update === nextProps.update
  return nextProps.update;
}
```

You can find more information here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variable called `cache`.

What this cache do is to check if your_awesome_api is called before.

This code below is a common approach:

```
// cache.js
let cache = {};

export default cache;
```

```
// someComponent.js
import cache from './cache';

// ...ignore some react component code...

componentDidMount() {
  if (cache['your_awesome_api']) {
    doSomething(cache['your_awesome_api'])
  } else {
    this.callservice(your_awesome_api).then(result => {
      cache['your_awesome_api'] = result
    })
  }
}
```

This way, you don't need to worry about re-rendering problem ever!

Re-rendering in react is really common!